# Prevent Prepos from processing certain scss files?

Tags: html, css, sass, preprocessor

I don't want anything processed except for my "main.scss" file. Is there a way to prevent Prepos from processing certain scss files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right-click on the file in `Prepros` and select Disable Auto Compile.

Answer (score 0):

Please select the project, then Files tab and then select the file you want to exclude. In the right panel under "FILE OPTIONS" you can deselect "Auto compile".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using partials, ie: _body.scss, then prepos will see that as a partial and not process it. Simply make sure that it is being imported into your main.scss. Also, once you create a new partial, go to Prepos and refresh the project. That will ensure it is seen as a partial.